# Animating SVG with CSS

Tags: css, svg, jquery-animate

I have a simple line SVG that is animating correctly. The problem is that on first load the SVG paths show and then disappear prior to the start.I have tried setting opacity on st1 and st2 to 0 and then keyframes to to opacity 1. This kind of works, but the SVG then disappears after it is run.

Am I missing something simple?

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 485 500.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 485 500.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
.st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-dasharray: 1000;
animation: draw 4s normal ease-in;}
.st1{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-dasharray: 1000;
animation: draw 4s normal ease-in;animation-delay: 1s;}
.st2{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-dasharray: 1000;
animation: draw 4s normal ease-in;animation-delay: 3s;}
@keyframes draw {
from {
stroke-dashoffset: -1000;
}
to {
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
}
</style>
<g>
<defs>
    <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="-0.1" y="0" width="485" height="501"/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
</clipPath>
<path class="st0" d="M0.4,97.4c0-14.2,14.2-14.2,14.2-14.2H100l5.1,0h86.3c0,0,14.2,0,14.2-14.2V36.4V0"/>
<path class="st1" d="M207.5,236.3l0-31.3c0,0,0-14.2-14.2-14.2h-15.1l-142.8,0.1H14.6c-14.2,0-14.2-14.2-14.2-14.2V103"/>
<path class="st2" d="M484.9,500.5H221.8c-14.2,0-14.2-14.2-14.2-14.2l-0.1-242.6"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

See:
https://jsfiddle.net/suLkr4po/

How do I restructure this so each path comes in after the other has finished from top to bottom?

Comment: Please update your example so the lines are visible. White on almost-white doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-fill-mode: backwards` to the style of the animated elements. That will apply the start value before the animation is started.